# QGIS to Unreal Engine (Possibly via Terraform Pro [Free]) Totally Stuck!

Tags: qgis

Totally in a tiz & getting really confused (as not a GIS sort), but I am trying to ideally get Full Topography data into Unreal Engine using QGIS, Ideally per whats in the OpenTopoMap & Ocean, depth/detail say like in Esri Ocean/sailing/marine chart & inland water depth/streams/rivers. Or better as did try downloading DEM Height data to then get even more confused.

This is likely what I will try to use once I can figure how to process all I need in QGIS, into Unreal Engine, I also have L3TD if any use, the tutorial, which will likely make lots of sense to you clever people....
 https://terraformpro.com/tutorials/tutorial-1/introduction/

As its an open source, free educational project/interactive story idea, even better would be someone volunteering to help with the know-how and who can output all the layers I´d need for 1M scale (if possible for the area Around & including St Martin in the Carribean. N018W064, N018W063, N017W064, N016W063.)

Obviously, if anyone could help directly I will credit with heaps of praise and link to our sites, social media as I will in regards to the sources of the Data used in the files created.

I myself am Autistic and have ADHD and the project idea is for kids & adults like me. The idea is to have a physical book, story that links into the interactive story/game. The interactive story in book and UE4 is linked to the maps in the covers of the book, front Ecology, back Weather more storms etc as set a little bit in the future where global warming has really hit. But dealing with the Geography/Ecology bit first, second weather).

[image: Story, Ecology]

[image: Detail as layers I need]

[image: Me getting confused]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: GDAL can translate to Unity (Unreal) gdal_translate –ot UInt16 –scale –of ENVI –outsize 1025 1025 srtm_36_02_warped_cropped.tif heightmap.raw > https://www.gdal.org/

Comment: Sorry, could you recommend a site/forum where I can be broader and ask for hands-on help, as due to the way my Autism works, I get overwhelmed with too much information overload?  IT´s a lot to do with ideally needing fuller more specific tutorials & help with better source data.

Comment: you could try https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/ or http://www.cartotalk.com/ or https://www.geospatialonline.com/

Comment: What a fun idea! I hope you find the sources you need and are able to make it work. For the map layers you need, try making a data request on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/. For best results, shorten the background story to a sentence or two, and include a list of the layers you want.

Comment: And speaking of information overload, this site isn't great at requests like, "Here's the very large project I'm working on, please help me get started." We're much better with requests like "How can I solve this *specific problem* I encountered while working on a larger project?" So once you get started on your project, if you encounter any roadblocks this is a good place to get help.